# Pub/media in magento2

Tags: magento2.2, php-7

How to remove all the images in custom folder in pub/media in magento2 programmatically. I am trying with following code:

```
if ($this->file->isExists($mediaRootDir . $imageName)) {
                    $this->file->deleteFile($mediaRootDir . $imageName); }
```

But it's only remove specific files in custom folder. Thanks.

Comment: Try this using command line: rm -rf <your Magento install dir>/pub/media/custom folder

Comment: I need to remove files programmatically